# Xamarin.iOS cannot run by error message "Could not copy 'some files' "

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022, apple-developer

I'm currently got a problem when I'm trying to build a Xamarin.iOS project in Windows 10 PC and I got following error. May I have any help?

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Could not copy "C:\Users\waic.dev.nuget\packages\microsoft.intune.mam.xamarin.ios\16.0.3\build\xamarinios10....\lib\xamarinios10\res\MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALPublicClientApplication+SingleAccount.h" to "obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\Microsoft.Intune.MAM.iOS.resources/MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALPublicClientApplication+SingleAccount.h". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. Mekim.BaSdSalesOrderMob.iOS

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Unable to copy file "C:\Users\waic.dev.nuget\packages\microsoft.intune.mam.xamarin.ios\16.0.3\build\xamarinios10....\lib\xamarinios10\res\MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALIndividualClaimRequestAdditionalInfo.h" to "obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\Microsoft.Intune.MAM.iOS.resources/MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALIndividualClaimRequestAdditionalInfo.h". Could not find a part of the path 'obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\Microsoft.Intune.MAM.iOS.resources/MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALIndividualClaimRequestAdditionalInfo.h'. Mekim.BaSdSalesOrderMob.iOS

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Could not copy "C:\Users\waic.dev.nuget\packages\microsoft.intune.mam.xamarin.ios\16.0.3\build\xamarinios10....\lib\xamarinios10\res\MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALIndividualClaimRequestAdditionalInfo.h" to "obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\Microsoft.Intune.MAM.iOS.resources/MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALIndividualClaimRequestAdditionalInfo.h". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.   Mekim.BaSdSalesOrderMob.iOS

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Unable to copy file "C:\Users\waic.dev.nuget\packages\microsoft.intune.mam.xamarin.ios\16.0.3\build\xamarinios10....\lib\xamarinios10\res\MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALPublicClientApplication+SingleAccount.h" to "obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\Microsoft.Intune.MAM.iOS.resources/MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALPublicClientApplication+SingleAccount.h". Could not find a part of the path 'obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\Microsoft.Intune.MAM.iOS.resources/MSAL.xcframework\macos-arm64_x86_64\MSAL.framework\Versions\Current\Headers\MSALPublicClientApplication+SingleAccount.h'.  Mekim.BaSdSalesOrderMob.iOS

I alredy added apple developer account into visual studio but the problem still exits...

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: Reboot pc. Delete all .bin and .obj folders in your solution. Build again.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for the response. I had tried but the error still here. Any other tips?

Comment: Do other apps also have this problem?